Handling Asynchronous API Calls with Ordered Results in Vuejs
In my project, I want to implement a feature that calls up to n APIs (where n ≤ 4) to fetch images and then displays them in a list. I use a state called listImages to manage this.
Here’s how it should work:

Call all APIs simultaneously.
Handle the result of each API separately (i.e., an error from one API should not affect the others).
As soon as an image is loaded, it should be displayed in the first unfilled index in the array:


Image 1 is loading (input1) -> Image1(Loaded with input2)
Image 2 is loading (input2).                   -> Image2(loaded with input 1)
Image 3 is loading (input3).
Image 4 is loading (input4).

I tried using Promise.all or Promise.allSettled, but it seems they don’t meet my requirements. I want to find a way to call APIs asynchronously but handle the results in the same array, maintaining the order of the requests. How can I do that?
Thank you so much!

In such cases Promise is used, you need to share the code that you have tried.

I tried using Promise.all or Promise.allSettled, but it seems they don’t meet my requirements perhaps your code is wrong, either of those definitely fit your requirements ... the latter more-so than the former

Promise.allSettled is the appropriate method for what you are trying to do.
Ultimately, you are looking to update your state each time one of your promise is fullfilled (success) or rejected (faillure) while executing all promises at once and waiting for all to settle.
As promises are chainable, you can start by creating your array of "fetching" promises, then iterate over the said array to add your callbacks and then call the allSettled method on your promise list to retrieve your images.
Supposing you are using the vue SFCs <script setup> (doc here) the code could look like so:
<script setup>
import {ref, onMounted, onBeforeMount } from 'vue'

const listImages = ref(['https://picsum.photos/200/300', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300'])
const imagePromises = ref([])
const loadedImages = ref([])

function fetchImage(url) {
    return fetch(url)
}

onBeforeMount(() => {
    listImages.value.forEach(url => {
        const promise = fetchImage(url)
        promise
            .then(image => {
                console.log('image loaded ', image)
                loadedImages.value.push(image)
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('error while loading image', error))
        imagePromises.value.push(promise)
    })
})

onMounted(async () => {
    const settledImagePromises = await Promise.allSettled(imagePromises.value)
})
</script>

<template>
    <div>
      <pre>listImages: {{listImages.toString()}}</pre>
      <pre>imagePromises: {{imagePromises.toString()}}</pre>
      <pre>loadedImages: {{loadedImages.toString()}}</pre>
    </div>
</template>

Here is a playground where the images are also displayed using the response from the fetch api.
